# Mixing RIA services and standard WCF services

Tags: silverlight, wcf, silverlight-4.0, wcf-ria-services

Is it possible to have a mix of RIA WCF services and custom WCF services hosted in the same project?

At the moment I have a server project hosting 2 RIA service classes, both of which work fine, and 1 WCF svc file, which loads up fine in the browser (e.g. http://localhost/services/service.svc) but when I access it through code in the Silverlight client, I'm getting a Not Found error.

I'm happy to keep debugging away until I resolve it, but just thought I'd check to see if I was doing something stupid first...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you should be able to host RIA and plain WCF services in the same project. Until now, I hadn't heard anybody report difficulty hosting them together.

Kyle

Comment: Thanks Kyle - you were answering as I was :)

Answer (score 2):

The answer is yes, you just have to be careful how you set up your web.config. The new .NET 4.0 multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" caught me out. I provided a relative address in the endpoint address, e.g.

> `/services/myservice.svc`

but in the metadata this ended up being resolved to:

> `http://localhost/services/myservice.svc/services/myservice.svc`

Which confused everything. Clearing out the address attribute of the endpoint and updating the references made everything work.

Comment: Brad Abrams has a blog post on exposing the WCF RIA as OData and SOAP through an addition to the web.config, at ... http://blogs.msdn.com/b/brada/archive/2010/03/29/silverlight-4-ria-services-ready-for-business-exposing-wcf-wsdl-services.aspx